# Switch to new observable with latest from previous observable as input

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream of request objects:

```
let request$ = new Subject();
```

And I have a function that takes a request object and the current app state object, and returns a stream of new state objects:

```
function stream(request, state) {
    // Return a cold Observable of new state objects
}
```

When the first request is emitted, I want to call `stream` and pass in that request and an initial state object, and start processing the states that it returns.

Some time after that, a second request is emitted. The first stream needs to stop and be replaced with a new stream that is created by calling `stream` again, passing in the second request and the latest state that was emitted from the first stream.

I feel like maybe `scan` with a higher-order stream can do it but I am stuck here:

```
request$.pipe(
    scan((state$, request) => {
        let previousState = ???
        return stream(request, previousState);
    }, of(initialState)),
    switchAll()
)
```

#### EDIT - Example

In real life, the `stream` function establishes a websockets connection to a server, sends parts of the request and state arguments in the request, and then emits new state objects as messages are received from the server.

To simplify for an example, let's say `request` and `state` are just numbers, and the `stream` function just repeatedly adds `request` to `state`, emitting one result per second:

```
function stream(request, state) {
    return interval(1000).pipe(
        map(i => state + (i+1) * request)
    );
}
// e.g. stream(2, 10) will emit 12, 14, 16, 18, ...
```

The desired output would be:

```
initialState = 10

request$       2------------5-----------------
stream(2, 10)  --12--14--16-|
stream(5, 16)               --21--26--31--36--
...
output         --12--14--16---21--26--31--36--
```

Notice how at the time the `5` request is emitted, both the `5` and the latest state `16` are required to build the next stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use `defer` to create some per-subscription state in which the most recent state could be stored:

```js
const source = defer(() => {
    let lastState = initialState;
    return request$.pipe(
        switchMap(request => stream(request, lastState)),
        tap(state => lastState = state)
    );
});
```

Used this way, `defer` will ensure that each subscription to `source` will have its own `lastState`.

Comment: With the addition of your example, the question is a little clearer, so I've changed and undeleted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator takes a function with previous state and the current value, the `initialState` also should not be an `Observable`.

I think this should work better :

```
request$.pipe(
    scan((previousState, request) => {
        return stream(request, previousState);
    }, initialState),
    switchAll()
)
```

Comment: For this to work, the `stream` function would need to return a state object, not an Observable of many state objects.

Comment: Could you add an example of the desired emited values for a list of requests to your question ?

Comment: Good idea, I added an example

Comment: cartant's solution works well, here is a stackblitz for the demonstration : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50618825